# Java: Access button in another class from thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have class1 and class2. Class1 is a UI, class2 makes changes to the UI. Class2 is shown below.

1) Is there a way to allow the entire class2 to use objects of class1 (`JButton btnStartFullBuild, JButton btnShutdownServer`, etc)

2) How do I allow the thread to change the background color of the button in Class1
(using: `btnShutdownServer.setBackground(Color.blue);` )

```
package examples;
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Class2 {

    public static void shutdownServer(JButton btnStartFullBuild, JButton btnShutdownServer) {
// This works
        btnShutdownServer.setBackground(Color.blue);
// This works when passing text, but I cant modify other classes buttons
        new ThreadTest("Can I modify a button?").start();
    }


}
class ThreadTest extends Thread {
    public ThreadTest(String str) {
        super(str);
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("Loop " + i + ": " + getName());
            try {
                sleep((int) (Math.random() * 2000));

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should know that Swing is absolutely not thread safe. While what you are doing may or may not work, doing it this way is not a good idea.

Comment: I realized I copied a part of code that wasn't being run. It worked after I edited the part of code that was actually running (I've been making lots of changes)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you probably don't want to, as `Class2` could do all sorts of nasty things you don't want it to, like remove the buttons and other components

A better solution would be to use an [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) to allow `Class2` to generate notifications that interested parties can respond to.

Also, Swing is not thread safe, so be careful when trying to modify the state of the UI from outside the context of the EDT.

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details and other possible options, like `SwingWorker` (which has `PropertyChange` support)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the previous answer that this isn't the most elegant solution, but...it looks like it would be possible to do this with `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`:

```
// from inside your current run method
public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        ...
    // access button here
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            btnShutdownServer.setBackground(Color.blue);
        }
    });
```

I'm no Swing expert, found this solution here: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/invokelater.shtml